# How to use both VPN and non-VPN at the same time?

Tags: networking, iptables, openvpn, vpn

This might be an issue with VPN configuration, but what I'd like to do is have a specific user account use a VPN connection and have the rest of the system use non-VPN connection. The problem I'm running into is I cannot seem to establish both a VPN and a non-VPN connection.

Some information about my setup. I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu Server 16.04 and am using OpenVPN to establish VPN connections (to the Private Internet Access VPN servers).

For example. If I run `ifconfig` I receive the following:

```
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fc:aa:14:cd:89:1c
          inet addr:192.168.2.2  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::feaa:14ff:fecd:891c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:638452 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:93481 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:901618753 (901.6 MB)  TX bytes:5702645 (5.7 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:176 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:176 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:12800 (12.8 KB)  TX bytes:12800 (12.8 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:60:89:9c
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Now, using the above interfaces, I can execute the following:

```
$ curl --interface enp2s0 icanhazip.com
```

and it will successfully return my IP address. Next up, I connect to the VPN utilizing the following settings:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote us-chicago.privateinternetaccess.com 1198
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
cipher aes-128-cbc
auth sha1
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server
auth-user-pass pia.cred
# route-nopull
comp-lzo
verb 1
reneg-sec 0
crl-verify crl.rsa.2048.pem
ca ca.rsa.2048.crt
disable-occ
```

It will establish a connection and provides the following from `ifconfig`:

```
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fc:aa:14:cd:89:1c
          inet addr:192.168.2.2  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::feaa:14ff:fecd:891c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:638594 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:93598 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:901632961 (901.6 MB)  TX bytes:5727985 (5.7 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:176 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:176 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:12800 (12.8 KB)  TX bytes:12800 (12.8 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.53.10.6  P-t-P:10.53.10.5  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:375 (375.0 B)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:60:89:9c
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Now, executing the following command will successfully go through the VPN:

```
$ curl --interface tun0 icanhazip.com
```

However, executing the following command will fail to connect:

```
$ curl --interface enp2s0 icanhazip.com
```

What I would like to have happen is, I would like to be able to connect through the VPN via tun0 and non-VPN via enp2s0. From there, I can set up iptables routing to route specific connections as needed.

**Update**: A comment recommended using a network namespace, so afearch searching, I found an [article on using a network namespace with OpenVPN](http://www.naju.se/articles/openvpn-netns.html). I am able to establish a connection with this command

```
$ sudo openvpn --ifconfig-noexec --route-noexec --up netns-script --route-up netns-script --down netns-script --script-security 2 --config 'US Chicago.ovpn'
```

However, when I attempt to make a connection using the VPN, it will simply timeout

```
$ sudo ip netns exec vpn curl icanhazip.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: icanhazip.com
```

Comment: Possibly related: [Is it possible to access a remote computer when it is connected to a VPN?](https://superuser.com/q/271415/354511)  and (maybe, somewhat) [How can I make the Windows VPN route selective traffic (by destination network)?](https://superuser.com/q/12022/354511)

Comment: You can't do this for a specific user. But you can make a network namespace, put the VPN interface in that namespace, and then all applications running in that namespace will use the VPN, while the rest of the system will use the normal connection.

Comment: I've updated the post, I attempted to use a network namespace for the VPN but still do not seem to be able route traffic through the VPN

Comment: since kernel 4.10 in Feb 2017 (and earlier on Android) it's easily possible to do this *without* iptables or network namespaces for a specific user: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564163/routing-traffic-for-a-user-through-specific-interface-tum1

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon the VPN server configuration how it has been configured. All the traffic has been routed through VPN in your case. By changing your default gateway for enp2s0 may give you your answer. Also, check for P2P IP link for VPN server by `ip neigh` command whether it is reachable or not.