How to route only qBittorrent traffic through a SoftEther VPN
I am looking to connect to a SoftEther VPN server and only route the traffic from qBittorrent through the VPN. I am using the VPN Client and vpncmd programs, all running on Debian. I have managed to connect to the VPN and even route traffic through the VPN, but it was all traffic.
Here is what I tried:
After connecting to the VPN,
ip route add (VPN server IP address)/32 via (previous gateway address) - add a route through the VPN
ip route del default - remove the old route
dhclient vpn_vpn - request an IP address
That did work, but it routed all trafic through the VPN, I tried without the ip route del default command and binding qBittorrent to the vpn_vpn interface, but qBittorrent had no connection.

I have never heard of SoftEther VPN before so I don't know if it does things differently.  But the OpenVPN solutions I've used give me an interface, so I would look at running your torrent client as a different user and then read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564163/routing-traffic-for-a-user-through-specific-interface-tum1

Yes, SoftEther also gives you an interface. I tried running qBittorrent as a different user, but then, the normal version can't run because there is no Qt platform, but there is a qBittorrent version designed for headless systems, qbittorrent-nox which you can manage only through the web-ui. I also saw namespaces were mentioned here and in other places as a solution to my problem, but I can't configure them right, I do not know what IP addresses to set. Also I'm thinking now that I'm typing this out, I probably won't be able to access the web-ui if I run qBittorrent in a separate namespace.

I haven't played around with network namespaces, so I don't know what you can do, but if you don't take care I think you can make the web-ui is only available for traffic coming over the VPN and you don't want that, but I also think it should be possible to make it work.

At least qBittorrent can bind to certain interfaces, so try it.

I mentioned near the end of my post that I have already tried binding qBittorrent to the VPN interface, it's probably not clear enough that I used the option built-in into qBittorrent.
